# Scala: Type matching of a type alias with upper bound

Tags: scala, typing, type-alias, upperbound

My question is simple.

Why does this code make an error,

```
abstract class A {
  type T <: A.Inner
  def toT: T = new A.Inner(this)
}

object A {
  class Inner(a: A)
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

<console>:16: error: type mismatch;
 found   : A.Inner
 required: A.this.T
         def toT: T = new A.Inner(this)
                      ^
```

whereas this code does not?

```
abstract class A {
  type T = A.Inner
  def toT: T = new A.Inner(this)
}

object A {
  class Inner(a: A)
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined class A
defined object A
```

`A.Inner <: A.Inner`. Isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, lower-bound should be used:

```
abstract class A {
  type T >: A.Inner
  def toT: T = new A.Inner(this)
}

object A {
  class Inner(a: A)
}
```

Only if `T` is ancestor of `A.Inner`, then A.Inner can be converted to `T`. We use lower-bound to restrict `T` is ancestor of `A.Inner`.